# Laravel: Can't update/delete Image on database API

Tags: laravel

I am currently trying to make a CRUD of Web Banner (Image) and the creating of image already works and it is already saving in my database but I need a function that will make the image be changeable on the postman when I look for the ID of that webinar.

I am in need of help in the UpdateBanner function. It is the one who will update the image of the given webinar id. This is currently my code:

Banner Upload Controller:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\Webinar;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class BannerUploadController extends Controller
{
    public function FileUpload(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[ 

            'file' => 'file|required'
        ]);
    
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => $validator->errors()], 401);
        }

        $uploaded_files = $request->file->store('public/uploads/');

        $webinar = new Webinar();
        $webinar->id = $request->id;
        $webinar->web_title = $request->web_title;
        $webinar->web_description = $request->web_description;
        $webinar->status = $request->status;
        $webinar->remarks = $request->remarks;
        $webinar->web_banner_profile = $request->file->hashName();
        $webinar->created_by = $request->created_by; 
        $webinar->updated_by = $request->updated_by; 
        $webinar->web_link = $request->web_link; 

        $results = $webinar->save();
        if($results){
            return ["result"=>"Image Added"];
        }else{
            return ["result"=>"Image Not Added"];
        }

        return ["result"=>"$uploaded_files"];

    }

    public function UpdateBanner(Request $request, $id)
    {
    
        $webinar = Webinar::find($request->id);
        if(is_null($webinar)){
            return response()->json('Record not found!', 401);
        }
        $webinar->update($request->web_banner_profile);
        return $webinar;

    }

public function DeleteBanner(Request $request, $id)
{

    $webinar = Webinar::find($id);
    if(is_null($webinar)){
        return response()->json('Record not found!', 401);
    }

    $webinar->web_banner_profile->delete();
    return response('Webinar Banner Deleted', 200);

}



    }
```

This is my Webinar Model if it helps:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Webinar extends Model
{
    public $table = "webinar";
    use HasFactory;

    // protected $fillable = [
    //     'web_title',
    //     'web_description',
    // ];

    protected $guarded = [];
}
```

And also my Webinar CRUD Controller:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Models\Webinar;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class WebinarCRUDController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $webinars = Webinar::all();
        return response($webinars,200);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->validate([
            'web_title'=>'required',
            'web_description'=>'required',
        ]);

        $webinars = Webinar::create($data);

        return response ($webinars, 200);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $webinars = Webinar::find($id);
        if(is_null($webinars)){
            return response()->json('Record not found!', 401);
        }
        return response()->json(Webinar::find($id));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $webinars = Webinar::find($id);
        if(is_null($webinars)){
            return response()->json('Record not found!', 401);
        }
        $webinars->update($request->all());

        return $webinars;
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $webinars = Webinar::find($id);
        if(is_null($webinars)){
            return response()->json('Record not found!', 401);
        }
        $webinars->delete();
        return response('Webinar Deleted', 200);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions and opinion on where I got it wrong on the UpdateBanner function, would be a big big help. Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What error are you getting?

As far as I can see you are not using the update method correctly. You need to pass an array to it.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#updates

> The update method expects an array of column and value pairs
> representing the columns that should be updated.

Like:

```
$webinar->update(['web_banner_profile' => $request->web_banner_profile]);
```

Comment: 404 not found. Actually I only need now on how to delete that specific column on the table. Do u know how? I already put my DeleteBanner function above. thanks

Comment: 404 means you are probably calling a wrong route (show your routes and where you call them). You don't delete a column, you just update it to null.

Comment: Do you know how I can make it NULL? the web_banner_profile? thank you

Comment: $webinar->update(['web_banner_profile' => null]);